# bsddb.open additional arguments

Tags: python, bsddb

The `bsddb` module has three ways to open a db-file:

```
bsddb.hashopen(filename[, flag[, mode[, pgsize[, ffactor[, nelem[, cachesize[, lorder[, hflags]]]]]]]])
bsddb.btopen(filename[, flag[, mode[, btflags[, cachesize[, maxkeypage[, minkeypage[, pgsize[, lorder]]]]]]]])
bsddb.rnopen(filename[, flag[, mode[, rnflags[, cachesize[, pgsize[, lorder[, rlen[, delim[, source[, pad]]]]]]]]]])
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html) says:

> The other arguments (excluding `filename` and `flag`) are rarely used and are just passed to the
>   low-level dbopen function. Consult the Berkeley DB documentation for
>   their use and interpretation.

But I haven't found the meaning of those arguments anywhere. Anyone knows the usage of this arguments? I think they may be useful to improve the performance of my db-file, I mean, `get` and `set` data faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [C API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/db.html#dblist) I see some documentation (but indeed it's hard to find). For example, for `bsddb.hashopen`:

- mode: [DB->open()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbopen.html)
- pgsize: [DB->set_pagesize()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbset_pagesize.html), [DB->get_pagesize()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbget_pagesize.html)
- ffactor: [DB->set_h_ffactor()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbset_h_ffactor.html), [DB->get_h_ffactor()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbget_h_ffactor.html)
- nelem: [DB->set_h_nelem()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbset_h_nelem.html), [DB->get_h_nelem()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbget_h_nelem.html)
- cachesize: [DB->set_cachesize()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbset_cachesize.html), [DB->get_cachesize()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbget_cachesize.html)
- lorder: [DB->set_lorder()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbset_lorder.html), [DB->get_lorder()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbget_lorder.html)
- hflags (not sure about this one, sorry)